# How to treat recursive navigation

Tags: navigation

Imagine the following navigation in a generic marketplace mobile app:

1. You can go from the product list to a product detail
2. You can go from the product detail to the product list by clicking a back button
3. You can go from the product detail to another product detail -- Product suggestions
4. You can return to the previous product by clicking back -- The same button that takes you to the product list

How do you deal with the recursive navigation triggered in the 3rd point? If a user clicks a product's suggestion and goes deeper in the navigation tree, it could be very annoying to click back N times to get to the product list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between going "back" and going to the product list. This will be contextually dependent. For example, if the user begins from a search bar that generates a product list, then they tap around through a few products, you will probably want a "Back to search results" navigation button. The reason you would have this at all is to save the user from having to remember what they searched for.

If the root of the app is a product list, just have a home button that you can get to from any page.

"Back" should always take you to the previous page you were on unless it tells you otherwise.